# Enhance the contrast of only a portion of an image using FFmpeg?

Tags: filter, ffmpeg

I am able to enhance the contrast of a whole image with the following command using [FFmpeg eq filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq):

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vf eq=contrast=2 -c:a copy output.png
```

But can I enhance the contrast of only a portion (say, the second quadrant) of the image using FFmpeg? I checked another post regarding [how to apply a filter only on a certain duration of a film](https://superuser.com/questions/977743/ffmpeg-possible-to-apply-filter-to-only-part-of-a-video-file-while-transcoding). Can I somehow insert something like `enable='between(x,0,10)*between(y,0,10)'` into the code above for my purpose? Thanks.

Comment: See [FFmpeg - Apply blur over face](https://superuser.com/a/901705) but switch boxblur with eq.

Comment: @llogan I tried the following code with mask.png (which has a white square at the second quadrant on a black background), but the mask does not seem to work. How should I fix my code?   

ffmpeg -i input.png -i mask.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]alphamerge,eq=contrast=2[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy output.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## square/rectangle area

If the area you want to apply the effect to is a square or rectangle you can:

1. [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) an area
2. apply [eq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) filter to the cropped area
3. [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) the cropped area on top of the original

Example to apply eq to the upper right quadrant:

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -filter_complex "crop=in_w/2:in_h/2:out_w:0,eq=contrast=2[c];[0][c]overlay=overlay_w:0" output.png
```

## complex shape

Use a grayscale mask that is the same size as the image:

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i mask.png -filter_complex "[0]eq=contrast=2[contrast];[contrast][1]alphamerge[alf];[0][alf]overlay=format=auto" output.png
```

Comment: Thank you. But sorry I do have a complex greyscale mask.png (same size with the input image) that I need to apply now. I followed the masking example in the link you provided and got the following code: ` ffmpeg -i input.png -i mask.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]alphamerge,avgblur=4[alf];[0:v][alf]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -c:a copy output.png ` And it worked. But when I replaced "avgblur=4" with "eq=contrast=2", the masking effect did not work. Are there other parts in the code I need to modified, too?

Comment: @isend eq doesn't support alpha, so alpga gets removed. Apply eq before alphamerge. See updated answer.